# В выражении «только и всего» слово «и» — это союз или усилительная частица?

Tags: фразеология, союзы, частица

> **Только и всего** (разг.) — только это, это всё, больше ничего.
>
> *[Толковый словарь Ушакова Д. Н.]*

Существует такой приём усиления, кода повторяются два синонима, разделённые союзом «и».
Например:
*Это касается **всех** и **каждого**.* (*«Каждый»* — это то же самое, что *«все»*):
*Это **легко** и **просто**.* (*«Легко»* — это синоним к *«просто»*)

Используется ли данные приём в «только и всего»?

«Всего» может иметь значение:

> 2. *нареч.* Только, лишь. *Нашлось в. трое желающих. Работа началась в. два месяца тому назад.*
>
> *[Толковый словарь Ушакова Д. Н.]*

Таким образом, «всего» может быть синонимом к «только». Например, можно заменить в предложениях из словаря выше:
*Нашлось только трое желающих.
Работа началась только два месяца тому назад.*

---

Тогда, в «только и всего» два синонима: «только», «всего» — разделены союзом «и», т. е. повторяется одно и то же для усиления.

---

Или «и» тут усилительная частица? Как понять?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что здесь два синонима. ‟И”, как частица, имеет 3 значения:

1. В риторических вопросах, как: ‟И как же ты могла так поступить”.
2. Соответствует слову ‟даже”: ‟Под лежачий камень и вода не течет.
3. Соответствует слову ‟ведь”: ‟Я могу и ударить” (Я ведь могу ударить).
   Ни одно из этих значений не подходит. А если взять другую частицу недостатка, как, например, ‟лишь”, то вполне сохраняется такое же значение, как и у ‟только и всего” – ‟только и лишь”. Заменим предложение: ‟Ты будешь приходить и отмечаться, только и всего” – на предложение: ‟Ты будешь приходить и отмечаться, только и лишь.” Конечно, звучит непривычно, потому что ‟только и всего” устоялось в языке, но, на мой взгляд, вполне заменяет.